# Removing gridlines from a table in Java but leaving a whole row the same color

Tags: java, colors, gridlines

I have used `TableCellRenderers` on a table to repaint cells so that every alternate row in a table is a different color, however, when I use `setShowGrid(false);` it removes the grid lines but allows the background color of the table to show through where the grid lines used to be, not the color of the cells in that row.

Is there a way to color these grid lines? Or do I need a better method of coloring the alternate rows?

Comment: I think that this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996200/how-to-hide-grid-lines-in-jtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the lines but left the spacing. Removing the spacing should work.

```
jTable.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to color the lines you just need to set the background color of the JTable component, but if you want to suppress it just set the intercell spacing:

- Suppress: jTable.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension([spacings]));
- Color it: jTable.setBackground([color]);

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.Dimension;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
  import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

  public class TestJFrame {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
      JTable jTable = new JTable();

      jTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new String[][] { new String[] {"col1", "col2"}, new String[] {"col1", "col2"}, new String[] {"col1", "col2"}}, new String[] {"colHeader1", "colHeader2"}));

      final TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer = jTable.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);

      jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer() {

          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
              Component result = defaultRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

              if(!isSelected) {
                  if (row%2 == 0) {
                      result.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                  } else {
                      result.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                  }
              }

              return result;
          }
      });

      jTable.setBackground(Color.RED);
      jTable.setShowGrid(false);
      //jTable.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));

      jFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      jFrame.add(jTable.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      jFrame.add(jTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      jFrame.pack();
      jFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
  ```