# How to hide thin vertical lines in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image: Vertical lines when row is selected]

How to hide this lines when row is selected in `JTable`?

I set to `false`: `showVerticalLines`, `showGrid`.
Also setBorder to zero does not help.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));
```

Maybe this is the problem. It's hard to be sure, because I don't know your code.

Comment: Yes that did it, just found answer on related post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996200/how-to-hide-grid-lines-in-jtable?rq=1

Comment: I will but need to wait for 6 more minutes